# не понимаю в чем заключается ошибка

Tags: python, django, миграция

вот код:

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    Article_title = models.CharField('название статьи', max_length = 50),
    Article_text = models.TextField('текст статьи', max_length = 1000),
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('дата публикации');

class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE),
    author_name = models.CharField('имя автора', max_length = 50),
    comment_text = models.CharField('текст коментария', max_length = 500)
```

вот ошибка: IndentationError: unexpected indent

я пытаюсь создать миграции

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в отступе. Короче просто убирай отступы до тех пор пока строка с ошибкой не перейдет на предыдущую строку кода. Как дошел до прошлой строки жми enter и у тебя ставится правильный отступ. У меня у самого такое бывает, хотя отступ на нужном месте, но ошибка только так фиксится у меня